# Can I use a gradient as the selected color in a box-shadow

Tags: gradient, shadow, css

I would like to make a box-shadow appear darker on one side than another.

I would like to do something like the following:

```
box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc, #fff);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox, at least, won't let you do this. Firefox only supports `linear-gradient` in a `background-image` style.

Even for browsers that may allow gradients in more places than Firefox does, they probably wouldn't allow this particular usage. In general, the gradient properties are only meant to work in places in CSS where images are allowed, not to replace "normal" colors.

You could do something sneaky like making a gradient the background-image of an element that's behind the one you're setting this box-shadow on, which you could use make it appear like the shadow is darker on one side. That's going to be quite a bit more complicated in terms of markup and styling, though.

Comment: I tried the above live in firefox (6) and it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: You tried the code you posted in your question? My answer was trying to say that Firefox definitely *doesn't* support that, and it's likely that no browser does or will.